# Use of row rank and column rank in regression

Tags: multiple-regression

I am struggling to understand full column rank vs. full row rank to estimate parameters of multivariate regression case. When do we use row rank, and when do we use column rank?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't at all clear- "full column rank" (or "full row rank") is a condition that a matrix may or may not satisfy, but it's not a formula that can be used in a calculation.

In fitting a linear regression model of the form

$y=X\beta + \epsilon $

by least squares, if the matrix $X$ has full column rank, then the matrix $X^{T}X$ is invertible, and you can write the unique solution to the least squares problem as

$ \hat{\beta}= (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y $

If the matrix $X$ does not have full column rank, then $X^{T}X$ doesn't have full rank, so the inverse doesn't exist and this formula can't be used.

It seems likely that you're confused by something that you've read about linear regression.  However, unless you're more specific it's unlikely that anyone here will be able to resolve your confusion...

Comment: why do we even need to use XTX and not simply XTy ?